# How do Yarn Scheduler redistributes the resources from an application that is using 100% cluster resource?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

With only root queue in YARN, let say an application A-1 is running in the cluster alone and it is taking full cluster resource. Now when another application A-2 comes to Yarn how does yarn manages/distributes the resource?? 
How does its recaptures its resources from application A-1 and make sure A-1 is using its own share??

Does this taking back of resources work similarly for both **FAIR and Capacity scheduler**?? Or they have difference in logic to distribute the load in this scenario??

Let say i have 3 queues q1, q2, q3 . And there is no Max-Resource constraint on the queues. So if q1 is taking full resource when q2 & q3 are idle. But when application start coming to the q2  & q3 ,then how how Yarn re distributes in resources??